# Calculating the number of rotations of an array to return to rotation 0

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Apologies that my math lingo is not correct, and for not necessarily knowing even the correct tags for this question!

> Let's say that I have an array of length *n* and I am given a number *r*.
>
> After stepping through each element of the array, I rotate the array by *r* positions.
>
> For example, if my original array is
>   **0, 1, 2, 3, 4**
>   and my *r* value is 2, after the first rotation, the array will now be
>   **2, 3, 4, 0, 1**
>
> If the original array is **0, 1, 2, 3**
>   and my *r* value is 2, after the first rotation, the array will now be
>   **2, 3, 0, 1**
>
> I then step through the rotated array and repeat.
>
> How many times will I need to walk through the the array/rotate process for the array to be rotated back into the original position?

To answer one of the questions, let's just assume all the values in the array are different, as I'm really concerned with the position of the elements returning to their original position.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "*stepping through each element*"?  Are all elements in the array distinct or is there possible repitition?  The answer will depend on the symmetry of the array if you have repititions, e.g. $(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)$ rotated twice to the right will again result in $(1,0,1,0,\dots)$ though it was a different "$1$" at the beginning of each.  Can you write an example of what happens, say for $n=4,r=2$ and for $n=5,r=2$?

Comment: It isn't clear at all what you mean by "rotate the array". You should take an example.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for the order of the element $(1,2,3,\dots,n)^r$ in the group $S_n$ which will be $n/\gcd(n,r)$

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm asking about when the indexes of the elements will return to their original position.

Comment: How do you calculate $r$?

Comment: @RobArthan $r$ and $n$ are given at the start of the problem is my understanding, that it goes for $n=5$ and $r=2$: $01234\mapsto 23401\mapsto 40123\mapsto 12340\mapsto 34012\mapsto 01234$ taking in this case $5/\gcd(5,2)=5$ rotations.  Meanwhile for $r=2,n=4$ one has $0123\mapsto 2301\mapsto 0123$ which took $4/\gcd(4,2)=2$ rotations.

Comment: The only step left is to *prove* my claim is correct.  Note that the subgroup generated by $(1,2,\dots,n)$ in $S_n$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z_n, +)$ and note that $\gcd(n,r)\cdot \text{lcm}(n,r)=nr$.  Note now that $r\cdot (n/\gcd(n,r))=\text{lcm}(n,r)$ which is a multiple of $n$, so $n/\gcd(n,r)$ rotations of size $r$ will indeed result in a return to the beginning.  Now, one needs to show that no smaller number of rotations will result in a return to the beginning (*except zero*).  To do this, use the specific properties of $\gcd$ and $\text{lcm}$ being greatest and least respectively.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the question to clarify the point that $r$ is given and fixed throughout the computation. @olynoise: please check that my edit is OK.

Comment: @RobArthan yes, great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We are given a sequence (array) of $n$ elements. When this sequence is rotated (shifted left circularly) as described by $r$ positions, we call it "one rotation". We need to find, after how many rotations will the sequence be same as the original one.

Consider the element at an arbitrary index $i$ in the original sequence. A single rotation places this at index $(i-r)\bmod n$. After $j$ rotations, it will have moved to index: $(i-jr)\bmod n$.

We will arrive at the original sequence when:

$(i-jr)\bmod n = i$

$\Leftrightarrow jr = $ a multiple of $n$, say $qn$

Since we are looking for the first time it happens, we need to find minimum such $j$, which means:

$jr = qn = lcm(r,n)$

$\Leftrightarrow j = \dfrac{lcm(r,n)}{r} = \dfrac{rn}{gcd(r,n)r} = \dfrac{n}{gcd(r,n)}.$